# How do we register a Multiplatform App to receive notifcations in iOS 14?

Tags: ios, swiftui, apple-push-notifications, multiplatform, ios14

On iOS the main app is as follows:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

AppDelegate is no longer in the Multiplatform app project type, how do we register the app to receive notifications and register the mobile devices?

I know how to do it in the AppDelegate, but without AppDelegate, I have no clue how to register for notifications.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor and it’s NS* equivalent. They let you provide a class that will be used as the app delegate. Example: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-uiapplicationdelegateadaptor-property-wrapper

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, all I needed to add was UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to the class: i.e. class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {...

Comment: When building for Mac, does it just ignore the UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor call, and vice versa for iOS and NS?

Comment: You probably need to wrap them, e.g. 
#if os(iOS)
// UIApplication…
#else
// NSApplication…
#endif